# Match two columns in table to two columns in separate table and return value

Tags: excel

I have two tables on separate sheets in the same workbook.

Trying to explain: I am trying to return the length in worksheet("LENGTHS") to worksheet("CONTROL"). Basically, if D3&E3 (Ex. L1a) matches worksheet("LENGTHS")B:B&C:C, return value in column D to worksheet("CONTROL")column G.

Worksheet("[CONTROL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4oscz.png)")
Worksheet("[LENGTHS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4yhWd.png)")

I am able to match just the "REF:" columns with:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Table2[[#All],[Linear Length:]],MATCH([@[REF:]],Table2[[#All],[REF:]],0)),"")
```

However, I need to match the extensions in the adjacent column as well. I tried adding it with "&" but it returns a blank cell:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Table2[[#All],[Linear Length:]],MATCH([@[REF:]]&[@[(extension)]],Table2[[#All],[REF:]]&Table2[[#All],[Extension:]],0)),"")
```

Any suggestions appreciated. Writing a macro might take less space?

Comment: Did you enter the second with Ctrl-Shift-Enter when done editing? If done correctly excel will put {}around the formula. It is an array.

Comment: Thanks Scott. That worked (or cmd-shift-enter in my case with Mac). I have  had many troubles with array formulas in that they don't always update automatically, but right now they seem to be working. Thanks

Comment: Considering previous issues with array formulas; would it be possible to do this without using array?

Comment: There are 1 step methods that use Array formulas that do not require CSE.  There are other two or three step process that remove the need for array formulas all together.  For example you would create two helper columns, one in each of your tables that concatenates the two fields.  Then you can use your simple INDEX/MATCH formula on those helper columns.