# Retrieve Cell Value in a separate column of Sheet 2 if Values from two columns in Sheet1 Match two columns in Sheet2

Tags: excel, indexing, excel-formula, match, multiple-columns

**Intended behaviour**
Where two values in the same row of two different columns MATCH two values in the same row of two different columns in *another* sheet, the data in the same row of the third column of the additional sheet is displayed in a third column of the original sheet.

*For example...*
Where Sheet1 A2 ("1") *AND* B2 ("A") **MATCH** Sheet2 A5 ("1) AND B5 ("A"), the value in Sheet2 D5 (1500%) should be displayed in C2 of Sheet1

[image]

[image]

I have read the below similar questions:

> [Match two columns in table to two columns in separate table and return value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36913168/match-two-columns-in-table-to-two-columns-in-separate-table-and-return-value) &
>
> [Match values in two columns and return value using vlookup from third column in Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35676773/match-values-in-two-columns-and-return-value-using-vlookup-from-third-column-in)

and tried working them into my spreadsheet but the data I get back is either a "" (blank), "#VALUE" or "#NA"

The below formula seems to be the closest potential resolution but sadly it's spitting out blank from what seems to be an error

I have also tried the below formula with CSE (Ctrl +Shift + Enter) but nothing

`=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet2!D2:D7, MATCH(Sheet1!A2:A7,Sheet2!A2:A7,0),MATCH(Sheet1!B2:B7,Sheet2!B2:B7,0)),)`

Any assistance would be appreciated for this excel noob, thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this in your Sheet1!C2:

`=INDEX(Sheet2!$D$2:$D$7,MATCH(1,(Sheet2!$A$2:$A$7=Sheet1!A2)*(Sheet2!$B$2:$B$7=Sheet1!B2),0))`

Comment: and sure it needs to be covered by `IFERROR()` if you want

Comment: Please give it CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER if it does not work. It works with ENTER in my EXCEL 365.

Comment: Amazing! Thank you so much for the help 